# Microsoft Owin Cors allow all not working in Chrome for Web API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, cors, owin

I have created on JS SPA which calls Web API. I am using CORS to allow all request for Web Api using tag "**assembly: OwinStartup**" and "**app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);**"

Complete application [here](https://github.com/ghorui/LocationSvc)

For Edge request is successful whereas in Chrome it is not. I am getting error: **Failed to load https://localhost:44373/api/location?cityName=dc: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:44392' is therefore not allowed access.**

Interesting part is I am unable to see any "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" request header for both in Developer tool.

For Chrome:

:authority:localhost:44373
:method:GET
:path:/api/location?cityName=dc
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8
cache-control:no-cache
origin:https://localhost:44392
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://localhost:44392/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36

For Edge:

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, peerdist
Accept-Language: en-US
Host: localhost:44373
Origin: https://localhost:44392
Referer: https://localhost:44392/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
X-P2P-PeerDist: Version=1.1
X-P2P-PeerDistEx: MinContentInformation=1.0, MaxContentInformation=2.0

My start up page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFrxj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess for it "working" in Edge is because it's detected **localhost** and decided not to do a CORS check; but Chrome will always do the check.

Anyways, you're not seeing the header because its not there. To get it working, do the following:

Add these 2 packages: **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin** and **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb**

Comment out `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` from the `global.asax` file because we want to use OWIN for Web API.

Replace `Configuration()` with this code in your `StartUp`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Comment: Hey Man.. Its totally worked.. Thanks @Balah for saving my life :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this line of code as the first statement in the startup class --

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
...
...
...
```

Comment: I have used the same. [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(LocationSvc.App_Start.StartUp))]
namespace LocationSvc.App_Start
{
    public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        }
    }
}